# Check whether the statement is true or false [TIFR GS 2017- Mathematics]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math, determinant

***Check whether the statement is true or false***

> Let $n>1,$ $n$ be a natural number. Let $S$ be a set of $n\times n$
>   matrices with entries are  $0, 1$ or $2$.The average determinant of a
>   matrix in $S$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

How to check the statement? It is not possible to find the determinant of all the elements of $S$ less than three or four minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that if we swap two rows of a matrix then the determinant changes its sign. This implies that there is a bijection between the set of matrices with positive determinant and the the set of matrices with negative determinant.

Comment: For even n can I say average 0?

Comment: Yes, the average is $0$ for any $n>1$.

Comment: How does it work for odd n?

Comment: @N.Maneesh In order to have the bijection you need at least two rows, that is $n\geq 2$.

Comment: So if $M$ is the set of $n \times n$ matrices with any determinant value then the average determinant of the matrices in set $S$ would be zero? I think from the above argument the values of the determinant mentioned in the question is immaterial?@RobertZ

Comment: @BAYMAX The hint implies that  if $S$ is a set of $n\times n$
matrices with entries in some given set of numbers $A$ then the average determinant of the matrices in $S$ is zero (which is NOT greater than or equal to $1$).